# unary operator expected in nfs mount shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mount, nfs

i just need safety process. nfs mount, data rsync, and shell ended.

```
rmv=`cat /proc/mounts | grep /mnt/nfs | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ $rmv != $@ ]; then
 echo "not mounted"
 else if umount /mnt/nfs > /dev/null 2>&1 || /bin/false; then
 umount successed
  else
  device is busy"
  fi
fi
```

is working but...

```
'[' /mnt/nfs '!=' ']'
[: /mnt/nfs: unary operator expected
```

i got using "$@" i think i was wrong expression. need other ways

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "safety process", etc. It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You're not passing any arguments to the script, so `$@` is empty, hence the error.  Using `"$@"` doesn't help because that's the magic "expand arguments but maintain quoting" expression, so it's still empty.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: just trying to freely rsync process. When operating the process, it can be umount by the crontab. @donatello

Comment: if [ $rmv != $@ ]; then that means check the mount. @MarkReed

Answer (score 0):

There are actually quite a few flaws in your initial script, and some unnecessary use of code/commands.... does this do what you want? Note - it's untested, but I think it's syntactically correct.

```
rmv=$(awk -F"[: ]+" '/\/mnt\/nfs/{print $2}' /proc/mounts)
if [ $rmv == "" ]; then
  echo "not mounted"
else 
  if umount /mnt/nfs > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "umount succeeded"
  else
    echo "device is busy"
  fi
fi
```